# Does stack grow upwards or downwards

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit, x86, stack

At some places, I have read that stacks grow from a higher address to a lower address, but when I checked it out myself, I noticed that it grows from a lower to a higher address. For example, I allocated stack for a thread at address  **2aba5ab06010**  and at some point found out its value to be **2aba5b7050f0**, which is clearly greater than the top of the stack.

But when I check the disassembly, I can see that function prologues subtract %rsp and epilogues add it, so in that sense, shouldn't be the value of %rsp less than the top of the stack. Why these contradictory results?

Note that I am using Linux on an x86 64 bit machine and the gcc compiler.

Comment: It depends, and why should it matter to anybody?

Comment: If you convert your addr (2aba5b7050f0) to a decimal value: 46979886371056 -- And do the same for the other addr: (2aba5ab06010)->46979873792016 => 46979886371056 - 46979873792016 = 12579040 --- So your allocated address is larger then the address at a later point. Which means, stack went from a higher value to a lower value.

Comment: Provide more details about your checks. It is not clear what exactly you checked. Also, `2aba5ab06010` is smaller than `2aba5b7050f0`, not greater. Why did you conclude that it grows upwards?

Comment: Sorry Andrey and w00, I had put the values in reverse order, now I've corrected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thread stack can grow upwards or downwards depending on the platform.  A typically way to check this is let **A** call **B** function and with

```
void FunctionB( int* FromFunctionA )
{
   int localStackVariableB;
   //Compare &localStackVariableB and FromFunctionA addresses
}


 void FunctionA( )
{
   int localStackVariableA;
   FunctionB( &localStackVariableA) 
}
```

now compare the address of **localStackVariableB** and FromFunctionA and determine the direction. Make sure the optimization is turned off completely.

Comment: Agreed on platform. But x86 Linux grows down - if that wasn't changed in 3.x kernel.

Answer (score 1):

In the old DOS days, it used to be that the code and data segments were loaded at the start of the memory segment, and the heap was above that. Then the stack was at the top of the memory segment and grew down towards the heap, while the heap grew up against the stack. Modern systems seldom has it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Discard the common prefix (`2ABA`), and you seem to be claiming `0x5A... > 0x5B...`.
It isn't, so the stack grew downwards.

Comment: Had put it in reverse order accidentally, now I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

It is usual, when you pass a stack address to a thread creation function, for you to pass the *start* of the allocated block of memory - this is the lowest address, and on a system like x86-64 where the stack grows downwards, this is the *bottom* of the stack.  However, the new thread will then start using the stack from the top - the highest address.

From your numbers, we can conclude that your allocated stack started at `0x2aba5ab06010` and was at least 12MB big - say, finishing at `0x2aba5b706010`.  If so, this would mean that 3872 bytes were in use when you took your measurements.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you allocated the stack at 2aba5ab06010, do you mean that you gave it a chunk of stack memory starting at that address?  Then your reference point would be above the start of allocated memory, but with only one reference point you can't really tell which way it is growing.